# jsoup how to println price from web

Tags: jsoup

I want to print the price from this site: banggood, for a product, this day for example is 5.37€.

I want to see only the price of this product.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.banggood.com/ESP32-Development-Board-WiFiBluetooth-Ultra-Low-Power-Consumption-Dual-Cores-ESP-32-ESP-32S-Board-p-1109512.html?rmmds=home-right-flashDeal&cur_warehouse=CN").get(); 

String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("Titles : " + title);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you try? Is there an error? Please post the actual problem that you have with JSoup.

Comment: one more with the corrections...
but with the answers ...

Comment: I only changed the title - you forgot the t in "println". Other changes I did not make. Please provide the problem that you encounter. Have a look into CSS selectors in JSoup. With them you should be able to access all info of the page in question. If you have other problems, please be specific and describe your efforts: See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The price conversion seems to be a javascript component. Using the `.now` css selector, you can get the default price in Rs. Try a js enabled headless browser (i.e. HtmlUnit) with the currency=EUR url parameter.